# Coloring dropdown

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I would like to make a dropdown in my black navbar, However when I try this the color of the text is blue and if I click it the background of the popu is white and interferes with my black background, So I would like to make it transparent. Using bootstrap **v4.1.1**

```html
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/home">home</a>
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01"
                        aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
                </button>



<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" href="/user">Users</a>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item" >
            <li className="dropdown nav-link">
                <a className="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Create new
                    </a>
                <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

So the "create new" has to be white and the page links have to be white as well. When I click on the create new the bow with the pages in it has to be transparent.

How would I do achieve this? 
I have tried to put this in my css :

```css
.dropdown a{
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

But when I do this it works however now the pages won't show up when I click on it, I just get a white box.

Thx

Comment: Please post all of the Navbar code, and with `class` attributes.

Comment: eddited the html code, I currently don't have any css code that changes the nav

Comment: Please provide a js fiddle or a code snippet so it is easier for us to help you

Comment: I do not have js that does anything to the navbar, this html is my only code for the navbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `bg-dark` class on the dropdown. Also you'll want to use `nav-link` for the "Create new" link so that it's light like all the other links for `navbar-dark`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">home</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/user">Users</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Create new
                    </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu bg-dark">
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Page 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Page 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Page 1-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/VKvvHSVl98

Comment: this is what I was looking for tank you very much

Answer (score 1):

- You can replace your code with my code start doing css everything going to work nicely

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/user">Users</a>
        </li>
        <ul class="nav-item" >
            <li class="dropdown nav-link">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Create new
                    </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: You can replace your code with my code start doing css everything going to work nicely